# how to make javac to compile my multi language program

Tags: java, command-line, javac

I hava a java program which I wrote that in netbeanse. In my program I have some output like JoptionPane which include some non- english words (arabic). when I run that in netbeanse every thing is OK. But I try to compile my code by javac in cmd. javac give errors about them(Non-english words) and that is this  "unmappable character for encoding Cp1252". how can I compile my program. I want to add this which also I have a jar file too. to compile. My code is

```
"javac -cp jasperreports-6.3.0.jar; class1.java class2.java ".
```

how can I change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetBeans probably saves your source files in UTF-8, so you need to tell the `javac` compiler that.

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 MyClass.java
```

Comment: @nick Ok, I looked. Now what?

Comment: I am looking for combination of -encoding UTF-8 and -cp

Comment: @nick ?? Insert `-encoding UTF-8` after `javac`, just like already shown in this answer ??